# Cross Domain request with Ajax & JSONP is not sending session cookie in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am trying to send `http:` cross domain request by using jQuery Ajax with `JSONP` datatype but it is not working only in Internet Explorer (tested in IE11), It's working fine in Firefox and Chrome browser. 
I tried many tricks posted on stack overflow such as  `withCredentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header but problem did not solve for IE.

A sample code is given below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myurl.jsp",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: callback,
  error: callback
});
```

Can you please solve my problem?

Comment: errors in the console?

Comment: Which error you talking about please?

Comment: in the console man, do you have any?